# ArrayList add() method returns empty or blank firebase java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, arraylist

I am facing a strange situation. Believe me. New to using Firestore database. I have a collection as follow,

```
List<String> myStringList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> apiFutureResults = query.get();
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = apiFutureResults.get();
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.getDocuments();
for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: documents)
{
     log.debug(document.getString("myColumnName")); //prints value successfully
     String myString = document.getString("myColumnName"); // Same value assigned to String type.
     log.debug("Value of myString", myString);  //prints value successfully
     log.debug("Result is ::",myStringList.add(myString)); // prints empty or blank.
     log.debug("Arraylist size::", myStringList.size()); // Returns empty or blank.
     log.debug("Arraylist content::", myStringList); // Returns empty or blank  }
```

I was expecting **true** after addition.  In my case I am getting `myStringList.add(myString);`
returns **empty**.  String is fetched from QueryDocumentSnapshot (com.google.cloud.firestore).  In What scenarios ArrayList.add() method *returns empty.*  Or Is there any issue with this approach to fetch records from `Firestore`. This is not android application. Just a Java product.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing the value returned by `myStringList.add()`. I suspect that's not what you intended.  Printing the result of `add()` doesn't seem very useful for debugging purposes.

Maybe what you wanted to do is **first** add the item to the list first, **then** print the contents of the list.

```
myStringList.add(myString);
log.debug("Result is ::",myStringList); // print the list
```

You probably also want to print the list **after** the loop completes, not every iteration.

Comment: of course I tried it. When my list was empty I was inspecting `ArrayList.add()` end up adding that specific code.  If my list has a expected string I never go to check how add() really works.  @Doug Stevenson